# Dart: Suddenly have Error "Unable to run pub"

Tags: dart, dart-pub

I can no longer build my application from the Tools menu "Pub Build - debug"
The window alert is:

```
Unable to run pub
Please select a pubspec.yaml file before running pub.
```

How does one 'select' a pubspec.yaml file?  I have it highlighted in the editor so that's not it.  I've restarted the editor and when that didn't work I rebooted.  Other pub functions work.

If I open the pubspec.yaml file and click on "run build debug" in the editor it does build.  I've not added any imports recently.

Is there a configuration file that might be corrupted?

Comment: Do you use DartEditor? Use the context menu of the pubspec.yaml file.

Comment: OK, that still works ...  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Either select the `pubspec.yaml` in the project view and then use `Tools > Pub build` or use the context menu on the `pubspec.yaml` file in the project view.

Comment: Looking around, I see this is a bug with a confusing history because it seems to be sporadic. Yesterday I was able to pub all day, today selecting pubspec.yaml or the project didn't help - restarting Dart Editor (1.10.1) did, though. No idea how to reproduce!